# null pointer error when trying to add to arrayList that holds my observers

Tags: java, android

I'm doing an exercise on the observable design pattern. I have a dialog fragment where I will be selecting a font and then notifying an activity that the font has changed.

In my dialog I set up an arrayList that uses an interface that my activity implements as its generic type. I declare it as so

```
 private ArrayList<CustomStyleInterface> observers;
```

I then create it in the onCreateView method

```
observers = new ArrayList<CustomStyleInterface>();
```

then I have a public method to add the observers to the array

```
public void  addListener(CustomStyleInterface listener) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Listener: " + listener);
    observers.add(listener);
}
```

In my activity which implements the CustomeStyleInterface interface when I create the dialog I have this code

```
CustomStyleDialogFragment customDialog = new CustomStyleDialogFragment();
customDialog.addListener(this);
```

that is causing the null pointer error. My log is showing something being passed in tho. I've spend a couple hours on this and cant figure it out, so any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you very much

logcat paste of log tag and error below

```
.CustomStyleDialogFragment( 2877): Listener: com.bloc.blocnotes.BlocNotes@528160e8
AndroidRuntime( 2877): Shutting down VM
dalvikvm( 2877): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4cb3b20)
AndroidRuntime( 2877): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
AndroidRuntime( 2877): Process: com.bloc.blocnotes, PID: 2877
AndroidRuntime( 2877): java.lang.NullPointerException
AndroidRuntime( 2877):        at com.bloc.blocnotes.CustomStyleDialogFragment.addListener(CustomStyleDialogFragment.ja
:68)
AndroidRuntime( 2877):        at com.bloc.blocnotes.BlocNotes.onOptionsItemSelected(BlocNotes.java:118)
AndroidRuntime( 2877):        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2600)
AndroidRuntime( 2877):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1012

AndroidRuntime( 2877):        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:
1)
AndroidRuntime( 2877):        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
AndroidRuntime( 2877):        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:884)
AndroidRuntime( 2877):        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
AndroidRuntime( 2877):        at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:546)
AndroidRuntime( 2877):        at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:115

AndroidRuntime( 2877):        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
AndroidRuntime( 2877):        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
AndroidRuntime( 2877):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
AndroidRuntime( 2877):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
AndroidRuntime( 2877):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
AndroidRuntime( 2877):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
AndroidRuntime( 2877):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
AndroidRuntime( 2877):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
AndroidRuntime( 2877):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
AndroidRuntime( 2877):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
AndroidRuntime( 2877):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

```

Comment: Have you debugged to see that onCreateView() is called before addListener()?

Comment: Since I can't see the entire code, I have to speculate. I have a feeling that your fragment has not called `onCreateView` yet. So the thing being passed in exists, but not the arraylist. Pretty sure fragments only use createView when they are actually added to a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're adding the listener before the `onCreateView` has fired. You can confirm this by putting some logging in your `onCreateView` method and seeing whether it turns up in the logcat.

When you create the dialog, the view itself hasn't been built, so you can't add listeners at that point.

Change the declaration to

```
private ArrayList<CustomStyleInterface> observers = new ArrayList<CustomStyleInterface>();
```

and then remove the line from `onCreateView`, so that the `ArrayList` gets created earlier.

Comment: That makes perfect sense and looks to be what is happening.

Is it bad practice to declare and initialize it at the same time? That would fix this issue

Comment: @DanielH Not bad practice at all!

Answer (score 1):

Initiate the `ArrayList` in the `CustomStyleDialogFragment` constructor.

```
public CustomStyleDialogFragment()
{
    observers = new ArrayList<CustomStyleInterface>();
}
```

OnCreateView is called later, too late.